# Stored Procedure code shortening and optimization

Tags: performance, sql, t-sql

This stored procedure takes user defined table type as parameter. It contains data imported from an Excel file. Values inside that type are the same as in `#InconsistentRestriction` temporary table. It's working fine, but since I'm not an SQL expert I'm afraid it's not written the best way possible (or not even close).

Combination of `TextRestrictionTypeId`, `SMSChannelId`, `NetworkId`, `GatewayId` and `CountryId` is unique and is used to recognize whether record with that unique key already exists inside `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions` table or not. If record with such unique key already exists we're checking for consistency. All values with the same unique key must have the same `PassIfMatch` (**`NULL` is considered same as `FALSE` when checking**) value otherwise they're considered inconsistent and should not be inserted, but rather returned to user to correct them and reinsert them. Once you find a record with that unique key inside table, you should retrieve it's `Id` and insert combination of `Id` and `Expression` into `dbo.TextRestrictionData` table.

First, I'm creating a temporary table which contains the same columns as my user defined table type `su.TextRestriction_Type`. After that I'm joining user defined table type input with `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions` table on unique key values and checking where `PassIfMatch` is not the same for input records and existing record. That way I'm getting the set of inconsistent input records and I'm placing them into temporary table.

Next step is the insertion of non existing unique key into `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions`. So I'm joining input user defined table type with `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions` and `#InconsistentRestrictions` using left join together with where condition to remove existing unique keys and unwanted restrictions from initial input user defined table type. Also, these record are grouped by because only one value of unique key combination can be inserted. By doing everything by now, I made sure every new expression got text restriction id existing inside `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions` table and I'm doing expression insert into `dbo.TextRestrictionData` by selecting `Expression` from input table and `Id` from `dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictions` table, also joining once again to `#InconsistentRestriction` temporary table to skip those invalid records when inserting expressions.

Lastly, I'm selecting inconsistent restrictions from that temp table in order to return them back to user to fix them. Hopefully I explained everything I needed to explain in order to help you understand my problematic.

Now, I'd appreciate if any of you took time to tell me if there is a way to shorten that code, maybe reduce those massive joins or even optimize what I'm doing, because these excels can get pretty massive amount of records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [su].[TextRestrictions_Multiple_Add]
    @TextRestrictionList su.TextRestriction_Type READONLY
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY

    CREATE TABLE #InconsistentRestrictions
    (
        TextRestrictionTypeId INT           NOT NULL,
        [Enabled]             BIT           NOT NULL,
        SMSChannelId          INT           NULL,
        NetworkId             INT           NULL,
        GatewayId             INT           NULL,
        CountryId             INT           NULL,
        Expression            NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        PassIfMatch           BIT           NULL
    );

    -- INSERTING INCONSISTENT INPUT RECORDS TO TEMPORARY TABLE (THOSE THAT HAVE PassIfMatch DIFFERENT THAN EXISTING MATCHING TABLE RECORD) --
    INSERT INTO #InconsistentRestrictions
        ( TextRestrictionTypeId, [Enabled], SMSChannelId, NetworkId, GatewayId, CountryId, Expression, PassIfMatch )
    SELECT   trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
            ,trl.[Enabled]
            ,trl.SMSChannelId
            ,trl.NetworkId
            ,trl.GatewayId
            ,trl.CountryId
            ,trl.Expression
            ,trl.PassIfMatch
      FROM 
            @TextRestrictionList trl
      JOIN  
            dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestriction tr
        ON   
             tr.TextRestrictionTypeId = trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
       AND  (tr.SMSChannelId          = trl.SMSChannelId OR ISNULL(tr.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.NetworkId             = trl.NetworkId    OR ISNULL(tr.NetworkId   , trl.NetworkId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.GatewayId             = trl.GatewayId    OR ISNULL(tr.GatewayId   , trl.GatewayId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.CountryId             = trl.CountryId    OR ISNULL(tr.CountryId   , trl.CountryId   ) IS NULL)
     WHERE
            ISNULL(tr.PassIfMatch, 0) != ISNULL(trl.PassIfMatch, 0)

    -- CREATING TEXT RESTRICTION RECORDS FOR VALID AND UNIQUE TEXT RESTRICTION COMBINATION --
    INSERT INTO dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestriction
        ( TextRestrictionTypeId, [Enabled], SMSChannelId, NetworkId, GatewayId, CountryId, PassIfMatch )
    SELECT   
             trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
            ,trl.[Enabled]
            ,trl.SMSChannelId
            ,trl.NetworkId
            ,trl.GatewayId
            ,trl.CountryId
            ,trl.PassIfMatch
     FROM
            @TextRestrictionList trl

     LEFT JOIN
            dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestriction tr
       ON   
             tr.TextRestrictionTypeId = trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
      AND   (tr.SMSChannelId          = trl.SMSChannelId  OR ISNULL(tr.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL)
      AND   (tr.NetworkId             = trl.NetworkId     OR ISNULL(tr.NetworkId   , trl.NetworkId   ) IS NULL)
      AND   (tr.GatewayId             = trl.GatewayId     OR ISNULL(tr.GatewayId   , trl.GatewayId   ) IS NULL)
      AND   (tr.CountryId             = trl.CountryId     OR ISNULL(tr.CountryId   , trl.CountryId   ) IS NULL)

     LEFT JOIN
            #InconsistentRestrictions ir
       ON    
             ir.TextRestrictionTypeId = trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
      AND   (ir.SMSChannelId          = trl.SMSChannelId OR ISNULL(ir.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL)
      AND   (ir.NetworkId             = trl.NetworkId    OR ISNULL(ir.NetworkId   , trl.NetworkId   ) IS NULL)
      AND   (ir.GatewayId             = trl.GatewayId    OR ISNULL(ir.GatewayId   , trl.GatewayId   ) IS NULL)
      AND   (ir.CountryId             = trl.CountryId    OR ISNULL(ir.CountryId   , trl.CountryId   ) IS NULL)
    WHERE   
            ir.TextRestrictionTypeId IS NULL AND tr.Id IS NULL
    GROUP BY
             trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
            ,trl.[Enabled]
            ,trl.SMSChannelId
            ,trl.NetworkId
            ,trl.GatewayId
            ,trl.CountryId
            ,trl.PassIfMatch

    -- INSERTING VALID NEW EXPRESSIONS --
    INSERT INTO dbo.TextRestrictionData
        ( SMSChannelNetworkTextRestrictionId, Expression )
    SELECT  
             tr.Id
            ,trl.Expression
      FROM 
            @TextRestrictionList trl

      LEFT JOIN
            #InconsistentRestrictions ir
        ON  
             ir.TextRestrictionTypeId = trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
       AND  (ir.SMSChannelId          = trl.SMSChannelId OR ISNULL(ir.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL)
       AND  (ir.NetworkId             = trl.NetworkId    OR ISNULL(ir.NetworkId   , trl.NetworkId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (ir.GatewayId             = trl.GatewayId    OR ISNULL(ir.GatewayId   , trl.GatewayId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (ir.CountryId             = trl.CountryId    OR ISNULL(ir.CountryId   , trl.CountryId   ) IS NULL)

      LEFT JOIN
            dbo.SMSChannelNetworkTextRestriction tr
        ON
             tr.TextRestrictionTypeId = trl.TextRestrictionTypeId
       AND  (tr.SMSChannelId          = trl.SMSChannelId OR ISNULL(tr.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.NetworkId             = trl.NetworkId    OR ISNULL(tr.NetworkId   , trl.NetworkId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.GatewayId             = trl.GatewayId    OR ISNULL(tr.GatewayId   , trl.GatewayId   ) IS NULL)
       AND  (tr.CountryId             = trl.CountryId    OR ISNULL(tr.CountryId   , trl.CountryId   ) IS NULL)
     WHERE
            ir.TextRestrictionTypeId IS NULL AND tr.Id IS NOT NULL

    COMMIT;

    -- RETURN INFORMATION ABOUT INCONSISTENT RESTRICTION RECORDS --
    SELECT   ir.TextRestrictionTypeId
            ,ir.[Enabled]
            ,ir.SMSChannelId
            ,ir.NetworkId
            ,ir.GatewayId
            ,ir.CountryId
            ,ir.Expression
            ,ir.PassIfMatch
      FROM  #InconsistentRestrictions ir

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Comment: Hello. Would it be possible for you to post your actual execution plan?

Comment: Other questions: What volume of records are we talking? A few thousand, tens of thousands, millions, etc? Do you have an indexing strategy on your permanent tables? If so, what do your indexes look like? Even good code can run poorly if the indexing strategy stinks. Still looking at your code...

Comment: You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to share schema and queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the clauses like

```
ISNULL(tr.SMSChannelId, trl.SMSChannelId) IS NULL
```

and

```
ISNULL(tr.PassIfMatch, 0) != ISNULL(trl.PassIfMatch, 0)
```

are [non-SARG-able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), and will thus force a table scan. In fact It is possible that your first large JOIN will be run as a single pass through a cross join of the two tables.

The first thing you can do is to recode clauses like (1) above as

```
(tr.SMSChannelId IS NULL OR trl.SMSChannelId IS NULL)
```

Ugly, but necessary.

However on those tables over which you have schema-control, such as `@TextRestrictionList`  and `#InconsistentRestrictions`, you can do better by making some of the nullable columns non-nullable.

NULL strings can often be converted to empty strings without any semantic change to queries.

NULL numbers can often be converted to one of 0, -1, or MinValue without any semantic change to queries.

Null Dates can usually be converted to one of '001-01-01' or '9999-12-31' without any semantic change to queries.

By performing these changes where possible you will both simplify your query syntax and give the engine optimizer better capability to use indices to optimize your query.